# How to share google spreadsheet without menu bar?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to share google spreadsheet without menu bar (File Edit View Insert...)?
Or how to hide main menu while sharing google spreadsheet.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

&rm=minimal works for me

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/VXjZXqYfCu4